# C# xamarin android Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts

Tags: c#, android, mysql, xamarin

I am trying to make a simple app that will connect to a database and get some info. I have implented the plugin that allows xamarin app to connect remote mariaDB/MySQL to components. I am using the code below.

```
    public void GetAccountCountFromMySQL()
    {
        try
        {

            string sql = " SELECT * FROM Kategorier";
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Persist Security Info=False; Server=192.210.241.161; Port=3306; Database=xxxxx; Uid=xxxxx; Pwd=xxxxx;");
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);

            con.Open();

            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString("Sko"));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I have tried many types of connection strings, also I buileded a simple C# application that connects to the very same database with no problems.

Comment: what exception are you getting?

Comment: I am not getting much information this is the output i get http://pastebin.com/gwTTr36c

Comment: So it is not throwing an exception?  How do you know it's failing?  Have you checked that you can connect to that IP from your device, and that there are no firewall issues?

Comment: It is not throwing an exception. Read the last lines of the output then you will see it says "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts."
as i said i tried to build just the same in just a normal windows C# application on the same pc and that works just fine

Answer (score 0):

Actual problem was error from MySql "cannot resolve host name" After discussion the decision was not to use this plugin as it is not secured but create a webservice talking to MySql DB and consume it from Android app.